# Mysql merge many rows into one with non-empty value

Tags: mysql

I have a table with data and structure like:

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| member_id | bank_name |  bank_ac  | ac_holder |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|        14 |           |   012-000 |           |
|        14 |           |   012-001 |      Andy |
|        14 |   CR Bank |   012-002 |     Jacky |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

What i need is to select one entry with all columns filled by the first non-empty value. As:

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| member_id | bank_name |  bank_ac  | ac_holder |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|        14 |   CR Bank |   012-000 |     Andy  |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

I have no idea how to start. Can someone give me suggestion?

ps: the empty fields are NOT NULL, they are empty string.
schema provided [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8ee3cf)

Comment: What is the logic by which `Andy` gets retained over `Jacky`?

Comment: thanks for help Tim, I need to have first non-empty value. Because Andy appears earlier than Jacky, I get Andy

Comment: Can we assume that there might also be two bank names?  Or maybe three?  Can we assume that only the `bank_name` and `ac_holder` columns will have missing values?

Comment: Sorry, it seems both bank_name,  bank_ac and ac_holder will have missing values

Comment: I'm not going to answer this question because your data is in a mess, and I see no clear way to rectify your situation.

Comment: Sorry for that,  anyway thanks

Comment: Is there a column that can be used to order the rows, so you know which rows are earlier?

Comment: MySQL doesn't have a built-in row number to order rows. If you need to determine which rows are earlier, it needs to be done with table data.

Comment: @Barmar Yes I can have an AI column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some aggregation

```
select member_id,
min(bank_name) bank_name,
min(bank_ac) bank_ac,
min(ac_holder) ac_holder
from demo
group by member_id
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6eee4/2)

If your data contains empty values like '' (note null is not same as '') then you can put case clause in aggregate function to skip these type of values

```
select member_id,
min(case when bank_name is not null and bank_name <> '' then bank_name end) bank_name,
min(case when bank_ac is not null and bank_ac <> '' then bank_ac end) bank_ac,
min(case when ac_holder is not null and ac_holder <> '' then ac_holder end) ac_holder
from demo
group by member_id
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bc4dcc/4)

Another workaround for your question

```
select member_id,
substring_index(group_concat(case when bank_name is not null and bank_name <> '' then bank_name end order by your_auto_increment_col asc) ,',',1) bank_name,
substring_index(group_concat(case when bank_ac is not null and bank_ac <> '' then bank_ac end  order by your_auto_increment_col asc) ,',',1) bank_ac,
substring_index(group_concat(case when ac_holder is not null and ac_holder <> '' then ac_holder end  order by your_auto_increment_col asc) ,',',1) ac_holder
from demo
group by member_id
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a745b6/6)

Comment: Thanks for help, I tried, but such non-empty fields are not null but "".

Comment: Hi, thanks for help. Here I try your sql failed under this situation: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a745b6/1    the bank name should get "CR Bank" rather than "AR Bank"

Comment: @user3711105 answer updated again for provided data set have a look http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a745b6/6

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid You have no `ORDER BY` in your `GROUP_CONCAT`, so the order is unpredictable. You're just selecting a random value from the group.

Comment: @Barmar there is not criteria available to order resuts in a group that is why i have not mentioned this clause, and i assume it will group records as per insertion order

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid He mentioned in a comment that there's an auto-increment ID column. You could use that.

Comment: @Barmar right i saw his comment and updated answer as well thanks